# What could have formed the pattern inside this piece of siltstone?

Tags: geology, rocks

I have what i think is a piece of siltstone with an interesting pattern on the face. It looks like a lichen or lightning bolt, as shown in the picture. The interior of the pattern is the same color as the stone itself, while the negative area is black. I was wondering what may have caused this pattern to form.

[image]

Comment: Where was the rock found?

Comment: A creek in Des Moines, Iowa

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. The photo is low quality so I can not say for sure but possible candidate explanations are:

- a septarian concretion
- a fulgorite
- a dendrite
- a differential staining based on differences in porosity

To get a better answer please include some close-ups of the central area and some pictures of the other sides of the rock

Comment: My vote is differential staining or dendrite.

Comment: @GaryKindel Indeed, in particular when looking at the lower part of the rock, the dendritic concretion seems the most probable one.